# How do I close a full-screen matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How may I close a full-screen `matplotlib` window? I spawned the figure using:

```py
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure('Optimizer')
plt.tight_layout()
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
```

However, `plt.close("all")` does not seem to do anything, and I couldn't find many things online to try that are relevant to full-screen figures. Seems like the behavior of closing figures differs for full-screen plots?

I have to manually `kill -9` the entire script for it to close. (Running on a Raspberry Pi if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

Alt F4 does the trick for me (Ubuntu / Windows). But I have not tried it on a Pi.

Comment: Just read the documentation. Default close figure keyboard shortcuts are ['ctrl+w', 'cmd+w', 'q']. So just pressing the <Q> key should do it.

Comment: I do not think that any manual way is an answer to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).